# While populating ListView with Custom Adapter it only populate first position

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have an app that discovers bluetooth devices and populates a listView with them. The problem is that it only populates the first position(and when receives new bluetoth devices replaces that first position)

```
 public void addItem(VSMDevice entity) {

        if (entity == null)
            return;

        // Update the information available int the advertising frame if the device has been already discovered
        if (data.contains(entity)) {
            // Update the advertising information only
            final VsmDescriptor desc = data.get(data.indexOf(entity)).getDeviceDescriptor();
            desc.setAdvertisementInfo(entity.getRssi(), entity.getDeviceDescriptor().scanRecord());
            desc.setAdvertisingMode(entity.getDeviceDescriptor().advertisingMode());

        }
        // Add a new discovered device
        else {
            data.add(entity);

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

This is the addItem code

This is the adapterCode

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<VSMDevice> data;

    public DeviceListAdapter(Context context) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void clearItems() {
        data.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(VSMDevice entity) {

        if (entity == null)
            return;

        // Update the information available int the advertising frame if the device has been already discovered
        if (data.contains(entity)) {
            // Update the advertising information only
            final VsmDescriptor desc = data.get(data.indexOf(entity)).getDeviceDescriptor();
            desc.setAdvertisementInfo(entity.getRssi(), entity.getDeviceDescriptor().scanRecord());
            desc.setAdvertisingMode(entity.getDeviceDescriptor().advertisingMode());
        }
        // Add a new discovered device
        else {
            data.add(entity);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        if (data.size() >= position + 1) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public List<VSMDevice> getItems() {
        return data;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DeviceListViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_device, null);

            holder = new DeviceListViewHolder();
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_device_name);
            holder.deviceIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_icon);
            holder.connectionState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_connect);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (DeviceListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        VsmDescriptor device = data.get(position).getDeviceDescriptor();
        holder.deviceName.setText(device.name());

        if (data.get(position).isConnected()) {
            holder.connectionState.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            holder.connectionState.setText("DISCONNECT");
        } else {
            holder.connectionState.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonColor));
            holder.connectionState.setText("CONNECT");
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this `data` and where / how are you calling the `addItem`?

Comment: can you pls post you adapter class code ?

Comment: yes give me a second

Comment: @user114023 I put the Adapter code there

Comment: @AsheraH the data is the array where the devices he found are